# Search custom properties in objects on the scene (Python)

Tags: python, scripting, development

Is it possible to somehow search all objects on the scene which have a custom property enabled using prop_search?

I know how to do this with dynamic EnumProperty but it seems to be not an option as it has some bugs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Blender 2.79 this possible by using `bpy.props.PointerProperty` and its `poll` parameter.

For example:

```
# define the filter method
def filter_on_custom_prop(self, object):
    return "MyCustomPropName" in object

# define the property by using the bpy.props.PointerProperty and its poll function
bpy.types.Object.my_object = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
    type=bpy.types.Object,
    poll=filter_on_custom_prop
)

# add to your draw code a `prop_search`
layout.prop_search(obj, "my_object", context.scene, "objects")
# or just simple
layout.prop(obj, "my_object")
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the API, it doesn't appear to be possible.

From [the API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=prop_search#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_search):

> prop_search(data, property, search_data, search_property, text="", text_ctxt="", translate=True, icon='NONE')

- `data` and `property` are the same as with a normal property. This may be like `bpy.context.scene` and `"my_prop_name"` respectively.
- `search_data` is the data to search in for the "property"
- `search_property` is the property to look for in the data

With regards to the last two, it would be, e.g., `bpy.data` and `"objects"` respectively.

I think a filtering technique like this would be better suited to the examples that @CoDEmanX shows in this answer:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8712/28015

Comment: Yeah, using prop_search to find all objects is easy. That's how it works now, but it is confusing for the user. Since I have fogs, liquids, portals and other kinds of objects using custom properties for my model fileformat.

I tried doing it with dynamic enum property using a callback... but the issue is that it does not memorize the item it has selected. So, if a list changes and items move in it, the order gets messed up.

http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74453/enumproperty-fill-dynamically-using-callback

Maybe you know how to make it work with dynamic enums or something.

Comment: I see...I think this may be better for one of the developers to answer such as @ideasman42. I may additionally help you out with a bounty, but the question should be edited to become more clear first.